# Dojo Set intermediateChanges on Textarea

Tags: dojo, textarea, onchange

When I use this in Textarea (template String)

```
`data-dojo-props='intermediateChanges:true' data-dojo-attach-event='onChange : update'`
```

The `onChange` event - fires on blur event to Textarea. My requirement is detect the changes once it was made from textarea.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are creating the Textarea. But, one thing you could try is to make sure the `parseOnLoad` is set to true or you are using `parser.parse()`;

**UPDATE**: If the templateString is what you have mentioned in the comments then it wont work. Textarea is a HTML node and not a dijit, so the property `intermediateChanges` does not apply to it.

Also, `dojoAttachPoint` and `dojoAttachEvent` should be `data-dojo-attach-point` and `data-dojo-attach-event`. I am surprised that its working for you, may be due to backward compatibility.

The events are case-sensitive for dijits, so you need to make sure it matchs in the template string.

I have working JsBin with TextArea dijit used within a templateString.
https://jsbin.com/cuyigizuji/edit?html,console,output

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi, I am using textarea as a template string.Check below code: this._contentWidgetString = "<textarea dojoAttachPoint='_textarea,focusNode'"
            +" dojoAttachEvent='onkeydown: _onKeyDown,onmouseout: _onLkpChange, onkeyup: _onKeyUp, onfocus: _showTooltip,onblur: _hideTooltip,"
            +" onchange: _onChange' class='contentWidget'></textarea>".

Comment: @Tushky Which version of dojo are you using?

Comment: @T Kambi I am using dojo 1.9 version.

Comment: @Tushky - Updated my answer

Comment: @T Kambi Thanks for the updated one.Just want to say that I have tried with textarea as a dijit,but didnt get any success. when I click on textarea, the textarea gets remove from dom and give me an error "TypeError: node is null" in console.
I am rendering my textarea in html file using ${_contentWidgetString}. Check below code:
      <div dojoAttachPoint="_containerBox" class="containerBox"  id="textarea"> 
  ${_contentWidgetString}
 </div>
Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: ` ${_contentWidgetString} ` syntax is mainly used for localization using i18n file, you cannot add a control. HTML tag might work as it is string substitution. But in case of dijit it wont work. BTW, why are you using it like that, If you want the control to be dynamic then create the dijit programmatically, in postCreate. If it is not dynamic, I don't see the point in having it as a string parameter.